# Spring Boot request Parameters not decoding '+'

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, uri, decode, urlencode

**This problem is only applicable to a few instances of our Spring Boot server in one environment.** A server is running several instances in three different environments(DEV/TEST/PROD). **The following situation works fine in DEV and PROD, as well as locally. It does not work in TEST.**

Search for usernames with a '+' in the end are not being properly decoded by our server. There is a search request being made by an axios GET call in the frontend, as so:

Search parameter: `username+`

The GET request would look like this: `https://tst.blackrock.com/atmosportal/api/search?search=username%2B`

In all other environments, our Spring Boot controller is able to decode the request parameter `%2B` into a `+` out of the box. So the service would search for `username+` as expected. However, in our TEST environment, it searches for `username%2B`.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: It would be best to provide a [mre]. Otherwise, it is difficult to answer your question.

Comment: If you're sure that the same build has been deployed to TEST as the other environments, then I would start to suspect it's something in front of your server that's causing the problem. Load Balancer, maybe? Are you sure you're making the request the same way in every environment?

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to tell without any source code, without you checking what actually comes to the Spring application. Anyway, since you're asking for "some ideas":

1. Rule out any external reasons - check what is really coming to the Spring app as the requested URL. Debug at the Servlet Dispatcher.
2. Rule out that the inner layers of Spring do it before it reaches the endpoint. That means, debug your endpoint itself.
3. At this point, it matters how are you taking the value from the request. Is it a `@RequestParam`? Is the type just a String? Or is it taken somehow from the URL after parsing outside Spring's features?

Depending on at which point it starts differing between the environments, it is either the configuration of Spring itself (more likely), or some pre-processing (less likely to interfere with URL params encoding).

So have a look at the profiles active on each environment, the beans active conditionally, extra Servlet Filters added to the chain, etc. Some of them active on the TEST environment may be accidentally double-encoding the param, or the opposite - for the other 2 envs, there may be a filter decoding the param, but disabled for the TEST environment.

That said: I came to your question looking for an answer why Spring is not decoding (unescaping) the query parameters.